# Iterate through CheckedListBox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, iteration, checkedlistbox

If I have Checked list box in Win forms which I fill like this

```
List<Tasks> tasks = db.GetAllTasks();
        foreach (var t in tasks)
            tasksCheckedListBox.Items.Add(t.Name);
```

How can I iterate tasksCheckedListBox.Items and set some check boxes as checked?

Thanks

Comment: Does the information returned by db.GetAllTasks() include whether or not the item is checked or unchecked ? Or are you determining whether or not an item should be checked after the ListBox is created based on some other datasource or criterion ?

Comment: I am determining its checked property only by its name GetAllTasks() method does not contains anything any info about checked.

Comment: So, something in the .Name property of each Task tells you whether it is checked or not : if that is the case, then I think you can adapt the technique in Jake Pearson's answer below. Then, of course, you are going to have to add some code to parse the string (which we must assume the .Name property holds) in order to determine the checked state. In a question like this, imho, it's always good to give as much information as possible about the criteria you use to determine how you evaluate data in order to set parameters. Good luck !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it after the items have been added, there is an example [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection.aspx)

Copied here:

```
private void CheckEveryOther_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // Cycle through every item and check every other.

    // Set flag to true to know when this code is being executed. Used in the ItemCheck
    // event handler.
    insideCheckEveryOther = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
        // For every other item in the list, set as checked.
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            // But for each other item that is to be checked, set as being in an
            // indeterminate checked state.
            if ((i % 4) == 0)
                checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);
            else
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }        

    insideCheckEveryOther = false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The add method takes an optional IsChecked parameter.  You can then add your objects into the checked list box in the correct state.

```
List<Tasks> tasks = db.GetAllTasks();
        foreach (var t in tasks)
            tasksCheckedListBox.Items.Add(t.Name, isChecked);
```

Or you can change the checked state of an item after you add it with something like this:

```
foreach(var task in tasks)
{
    tasksCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(clb.Items.IndexOf(task), isChecked);
}
```